# How do I get an array consisting of arrays where each sub array contains data from a returned mysqli row?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM cars, boats, estates";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
$result = mysqli_fetch_all($query);
```

My problem is that all the results just end up in one big array. What I want is that each row is it's own array which contains data from each column. How do I achieve this? And is there a way to reference a row item by doing something like $row['brand']?

Comment: It should do what you want. `mysqli_fetch_all` returns a 2-dimensional array. The first dimension is the rows, the second dimension is the columns.

Comment: you can't have sub arrays with each parent table along with children columns, it'll also overwrite same column names, if you wanted them differentiated, you'll have to have aliases prefixed in your column names to correspond to what table the column belongs to

Comment: @Barmar I know, but this is what I get:
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => x [2] => x [3] => x [4] => X [5] => [6] => BMW [7] => 520i [8] => 2016 [9] => 100 [10] => Automat [11] => Bakhjulsdriven [12] => Diesel [13] => BMW 520i [14] => Säljer pärlan [15] => Göteborg [16] => Sverige [17] => 1000000 [18] => 12 [19] => 10000 [20] => 2 [21] => x [22] => 1 [23] => [24] => [25] => [26] => [27] => [28] => [29] => [30] => Cali Yacht [31] => [32] => Los Angeles [33] => United States of America [34] => [35] => [36] => 0 [37] => 2 [38] => x [39] => x [40] => x [41] => [42] => [43] => Lägenhet ) )

Comment: That looks like what you want. `$result[0]` is an array.

Comment: The problem is that the array contains data from multiple rows, they are not divided into multiple arrays

Comment: No it doesn't. You're doing a join, which combines rows from each table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I was doing a join (selecting from multiple tables), everything would just mix up into one big array.

So instead I selected rows from each table separately and saved the result in separate arrays.

To solve the referencing problem, as @Barmar pointed out:

```
$result = mysqli_fetch_all($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$result = mysqli_fetch_all($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

to specify that you want the rows to be associative arrays. The default is numeric arrays. Then you should be able to use

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo $row['brand'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you my friend, that solved half of my problem. I basically need it to look like a json array: [{"var1":"9","var2":"16","var3":"16"},{"var1":"8","var2":"15‌​","var3":"15"}] where the var1-var3 is in $array[0] and the rest is in $array[1], is this possible?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "json array". JSON is just a format for converting arrays and objects to a string so you can send it over the network or store it in a file. It doesn't govern the way the array is organized.

Comment: Try to understand me, I'm not a dictionary or a programming pro that will get all definitions 100% right every time. At least I provided an example to show you what I mean

Comment: And I still don't get it. `$array[0]` and `$array[1]` both have `var1-var3` in them. Anyway, your problem apparently has nothing to do with arrays, and everything to do with writing the query that you want. You would have gotten the same wrong answer if you used phpMyAdmin.

Comment: I know, I saw that last night. It's not really an answer to the question you asked, it's an answer to a completely different question.

Comment: Lol it's true, should I delete the question to prevent future confusion?

Comment: I'm not sure you can delete a question that has an upvoted answer.

Comment: Ok, what do you propose I should change the question title to?

Comment: Flag the question for closing.